# why isn't ptrdiff_t the same as long long?

Tags: c

According to the current C standard, difference between pointers has type `ptrdiff_t`.  At the same time, according to the standard, a subscript to an array can be of any integer type, and the largest signed integer type is currently `long long`.

If `ptrdiff_t` were not `long long`, but smaller, then the above two statements would be a contradiction, would it not?

Then why does the standard introduce the type `ptrdiff_t` at all and not just use `long long` as the pointer difference?

Comment: The fact that `unsigned long long` is a valid type for array subscripts doesn't mean all possible values of `unsigned long long` are valid values for array subscripts. (Also, pointer differences are signed.)

Comment: ? Can you elaborate on your first sentence?  I don't get it at all.  It would seem to me, pardon my ignorance, that yes, these two things are the same.

Comment: OK there are already answers discussing that.

Comment: "a subscript to an array can be of any integer type, ..." --> If the subscript's value is outside the range of `size_t`, the result is UB.

Comment: @chux where does the current standard say that? I don't see it.

Comment: @MarkGaleck `size_t` is big enough to represent the size of any object, so its range provides an upper bound on the size of all objects.

Comment: @melpomene I see, thank you.

Comment: Qualification to my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964353/why-isnt-ptrdiff-t-the-same-as-long-long#comment69138592_40964353)  The subscipt range can be negative.  The resulting element index must be within the base array's range - or 1 pass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, `ptrdiff_t` is a signed type (the difference between two pointers can be negative), so that rules out `unsigned long long`.

An array subscript can be any integer type, but the resulting value has to be in bounds. For example, on a 32-bit platform you can't have an array with more than about 4 billion elements, so `ptrdiff_t` is likely going to be a 32-bit integer type. Indexing an array with a `long long` value that exceeds 32 bits just causes undefined behavior (ouf of bounds access).

As usual, the real reason is backwards compatibility: `long long` was added to the language long after `ptrdiff_t`, and `ptrdiff_t` was added after compilers were already written. It wouldn't make sense to specify completely different rules for pointer arithmetic (such as "subtracting two pointers must yield a 64+ bit result") when there's existing code relying on (decades old) behavior.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I think the important thing to understand for me, was that, once an array has been either declared or allocated successfully, then by definition the number of elements must have been small enough, maybe small enough to necessarily fit in a smaller integer type than `long long`.

Comment: "array subscript ... the resulting value has to be in bounds" --> in bounds of `size_t`.  `ptrdiff_t` is _not_ necessarily wide enough for all pointer differences - even within the same array. "If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undeﬁned." C11 §6.5.6  9  Yet `ptrdiff_t` is sufficient for most applications.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. `ptrdiff_t` can be an alias for `long long int`. It depends on the used system and the size of the address registers.

So an array can not be larger than the value that can be stored in an address register.

There is another problem that can lead to undefined behavior.

The problem is that the difference of two pointers can be a negative number. Thus you can not use an unsigned number as the result. Moreover the index also can be negative. For example consider the following code snippet

```
const char *s = "aabbcc";
size_t n = 0;

for ( const char *p = s; *p++; )
{
    if ( p[0] == p[-1] ) ++n;
}
```

It is a valid code.

So the pointer arithmetic needs signed numbers.

On the other hand the size of an object is determinate by the type `size_t` that can be as large as the type `unsigned long long`.

The problem is that the range of non-negative values of any signed integral type is not greater than the range of non-negative values of the unsigned type with the same rank. And absolute addresses stored in registers are non-negative numbers.

Comment: Yes my question was not precise about signage sorry...  But really, the question was not about that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to add to previous answers that pointers may be smaller or larger than data register size, depending on machine arquitecture.

Moreover, physical memory size may be bigger than the adress space.

Therefore, the variety of possible architectures is big and all them must be covered. So I find completely reasonable that pointer-related types are kept defined independently of data integral types, even if ptrdiff_t is an alias of some concrete signed integral type.

I always try to make my code as portable as possible, and to try to achieve that, I adhere as strictly as possible to standards and use the most specific standard type available for my needs.